# Remove array with duplicate value within associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
$arr[] = array('id' => '1', 'fn' => 'Some', 'ln' => 'Test', 'email' => 'email@test.com', 'dm' => 'test');
$arr[] = array('id' => '2', 'fn' => 'Some2', 'ln' => 'Test2', 'email' => 'otheremail@test.com', 'dm' => 'test');
$arr[] = array('id' => '3', 'fn' => 'Some3', 'ln' => 'Test3', 'email' => 'email@test.com', 'dm' => 'test');
```

I want to remove all dublicate keys $arr[] that have a dublicate email so that only this remains:

```
$arr[] = array('id' => '1', 'fn' => 'Some', 'ln' => 'Test', 'email' => 'email@test.com', 'dm' => 'test');
$arr[] = array('id' => '2', 'fn' => 'Some2', 'ln' => 'Test2', 'email' => 'otheremail@test.com', 'dm' => 'test');
```

I found different examples here but none could match my problem. Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
    array('id' => '1', 'fn' => 'Some', 'ln' => 'Test', 'email' => 'email@test.com', 'dm' => 'test'),
    array('id' => '1', 'fn' => 'Some', 'ln' => 'Test', 'email' => 'other@test.com', 'dm' => 'test'),
    array('id' => '1', 'fn' => 'Some', 'ln' => 'Test', 'email' => 'email@test.com', 'dm' => 'test'),
    array('id' => '1', 'fn' => 'Some', 'ln' => 'Test', 'email' => 'email@test.com', 'dm' => 'test'),
    array('id' => '1', 'fn' => 'Some', 'ln' => 'Test', 'email' => 'other@test.com', 'dm' => 'test')
);

$checkEmail = array(); // restore email values

for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
    if (!in_array($arr[$i]['email'], $checkEmail)){ // check in each array if email value is unique
        print_r($arr[$i]); // if unique then output
    }
    $checkEmail[$i] = $arr[$i]['email']; // save email values
}
```

**OUTPUT ->**

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [fn] => Some [ln] => Test [email] => email@test.com [dm] => test ) Array ( [id] => 1 [fn] => Some [ln] => Test [email] => other@test.com [dm] => test )
```

Comment: I also want to keep the indexes from main array

Comment: @user558134 Restore them in another array , index will be `$i` variable